# How to use excel for building sql-syntax

Tags: xml, excel, excel-formula

i've got a table of names and their name inside a DB, it looks like this:

```
     A    |    B
1|  abc   | dbo.abc, 
2|  def   | dbo.def, 
3|  ghi   | dbo.ghi,
```

i need them as xml objects like this

```
<Field name="abc" inDb="dbo.abc" />
<Field name="def" inDb="dbo.def" />
<Field name="ghi" inDb="dbo.ghi" />
```

in order to archive this i made up the excel-cells:

```
E1: <Field name="
F1: " inDb="
G1: " />
```

now for cell C1 i made this function:

```
=$E$1+A1+$F$1+B1+$G$1
```

but what i get is: #VALUE!

also it would be nice, if there was a way to chop everything behind and including the last ',' from my B-Column

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Excel function called **CONCATENATE** that can be used to join text.

```
=CONCATENATE($E$1,A1,$F$1,B1,$G$1)
```

Removing the comma and any data beyond the comma use the **LEFT** function.

```
=CONCATENATE($E$1,A1,$F$1,LEFT(B1,7),$G$1)
```

If your data in column B is a variable length use the **FIND** function combined with the **LEFT** function.

```
=CONCATENATE($E$1,A1,$F$1,LEFT(B1,FIND(",",B1)-1),$G$1)
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are adding words together in excel to make a sentence then you need to use and (&) and not add (+)

Answer (score 0):

cou can use the [`CONCATENATE()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx) function:
`=CONCATENATE($E$1,A1,$F$1,B1,$G$1)`

or the `&` concatenation operator:
`=$E$1&A1&$F$1&B1&$G$1`